# Convert float to int in Julia Lang

Tags: floating-point, int, julia

Is there a way to convert a floating number to int in Julia? I'm trying to convert a floating point number to a fixed precision number with the decimal part represented as 8bit integer. In order to do this, I need to truncate just the decimal part of the number and I figured the best way to do this would be to subtract the converted integer of x from floating point x:

```
  x = 1.23455
y = x - Int(x)
println(y)
```

y = 0.23455

Comment: The code you've provided won't work, since `Int(x)` will return an `Inexact error` unless `x` is a whole number expressed as `Float64`, e.g. `1.0` or `-44.0`. Also, I can't tell what you're actually after based on the question. Your wording makes it sound like you want the decimal portion of a `Float64`, expressed as an `Int8`. Is this right? That is an odd request, particularly given that for your example number `1.23455`, the decimal portion as `Int64` is `23455`, but this is obviously *much* too large to be expressed as an `Int8`.

Comment: Also, seems that you could use the rounding functions. All these functions accept target types for conversion: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-rounding-functions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are looking for `floor`:

```
julia> x = 1.23455
1.23455

julia> floor(x)
1.0

julia> y = x - floor(x)
0.23455000000000004
```

Comment: As of v0.6, note that the output of `floor` is not an `Int64` type, but rather a `Float64` as per the example: `test = ceil(0.2); typeof(test)`

Comment: `floor(Int,x)` is more accurately according to [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.floor)

Answer (score 45):

It is possible that you are looking for `trunc`. It depends on what you mean by the decimal part. This is the difference between `trunc` and `floor`:

```
julia> trunc(Int, 1.2)
1

julia> trunc(Int, -1.2)
-1

julia> floor(Int, 1.2)
1

julia> floor(Int, -1.2)
-2
```

Comment: `trunc` returns Float now, not Integer.

Comment: @karatedog `trunc(x::Float64)` has always returned Float. But if you provide `Int` as the first argument, as in `trunc(Int, 1.2)`, you will get an integer.

Comment: This should be the best answer

Answer (score 6):

To answer the general question in the title (convert Float to Int), we can do:

```
round(Int, 1.3)
# 1
round(Int, 1.7)
# 2
```

Comment: It is recommended to use the alias `Int` instead of explicitly stating the size of the integer, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Aliases-1

Comment: I'm sorry, but not why do `round(Int64, 1.3)` instead? It's much more concise? What's the purpose of adding an explicit conversion?

Answer (score 6):

Combining the previous answers:

```
julia> int(x) = floor(Int, x)
int (generic function with 1 method)

julia> int(3.14)
3

julia> int(3.94)
3
```

Answer (score 3):

according to `floor` [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.floor)
you can do that way

```
julia> x = 45.5
45.5

julia> typeof(x)
Float64

julia> x = floor(Int8,x)
45

julia> typeof(x)
Int8
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you really need is the decimal part of the number. If this is the case, you can use modulo 1 directly like this:

```
x = 1.23455
y = x % 1
println(y)
# 0.2345
```

Answer (score 1):

seems that you really need `modf` instead:

```
help?> modf
search: modf ComposedFunction mod1 mod module

  modf(x)

  Return a tuple (fpart, ipart) of the
  fractional and integral parts of a number.      
  Both parts have the same sign as the argument.  

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> modf(3.5)
  (0.5, 3.0)
  
  julia> modf(-3.5)
  (-0.5, -3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert Float to Int, this is a two-step operation. Because you must truncate the decimal part before typecasting it:

```
i = Int(trunc(1.23455))
```

Otherwise you can use `modf` to split a floating number into a tuple containing two floats that hold the integral and fractional parts of the original number.

```
(i, p) = modf(1.23455)
```